# Vue validation with Vuetify

Tags: forms, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js

I'm working with a form done using Vuetify and my question is, how can I add a success attribute to the `v-text-field` once the `input` has been validated by the `:rules`?

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="halfPayment.month"
    v-mask="'##'"
    :rules="[$rules.required, $rules.minCharacters(2), $rules.between(1, 12)]"
    label="month expired"
    outlined
    dense
    :success=
    background-color="white"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
:success="!!halfPayment.month"
```

to the text field to show when it successfully passed the validation rules.
I hope this helps, otherwise, you can just drop a comment!